# Форматирование в input ценовой информации c десятичной дробью

Tags: jquery, input, регулярные-выражения, javascript

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как во время ввода числа в input сделать так, чтобы оно динамически форматировало данные по три знака с пробелом и после точки еще 2 числа можно ввести. 
Например: ввод числа 1048766.75 сразу форматировало на 1 048 766.75?
Есть такой код, но он форматирует только целые числа:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.num', function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d\s]/g, "");
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "").split("").reverse().join("").replace(/\d{3}(?!$|(?:\s$))/g, "$& ").split("").reverse().join("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю несколько изменить код.

- Событие установить на `input`
- Использовать `replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$& ")` для форматирования строки (перед каждым проходом нужно удалять пробелы с помощью `.replace(/[^\d.]+|(\.\d{2})\d*$/g, '$1')`)
- Добавить дополнительное событие для обработки вставки точки (иначе можно отсечь уже введенные цифры).

```js
$(document).on('input', '.num', function (e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d.]+|(\.\d{2})\d*$/g, '$1').replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$& "); // Чистим и форматируем
  
});
$('.num').keydown(function(e) {
  if (this.value.includes('.') && e.keyCode === 190) {
    e.preventDefault();             // Нельзя вводить точку дважды
    return;
  }
  else if (!this.value.includes('.') && e.keyCode === 190) {
    if (this.selectionStart < this.value.length - 2) {
      e.preventDefault();           // Точку можно ввести только перед последней и предпоследней цифрой
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="num" />
```

**Внимание**: данный код поддерживает только 2 цифры после запятой, что соответствует критериям поставленного вопроса, но может не подходить в других случаях. Можно расширить поддержку до 3 знаков после запятой, заменив `.replace(/[^\d.]+|(\.\d{2})\d*$/g, '$1')` на `.replace(/[^\d.]+|(\.\d{3})\d*$/g, '$1')` и `this.value.length - 2` на `this.value.length - 3`.

Comment: Это было год назад, вряд ли оно еще актуально...

Comment: @stckvrw может быть, если кто то столкнётся с таким же вопросом